# Gear for an Inferno Wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What stats are best for casters (Wizard/Witch Doctor) doing Inferno?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72705/what-stats-are-best-for-casters-wizard-witch-doctor-doing-inferno)

I'm trying to rebuild my gear towards beating Act 2 Inferno, most of my gear consists of very basic 100 int/vitality, and rings with IAS (Increased Attack Speed).

Now I'm looking at buying in the AH, and I'm thinking of adding All Resistances on top of those.

Are there other stats I should care about? Such as Life regeneration, or maybe even particular resistances (such as physical)