# What stats should a Wizard invest in Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What stats are best for casters (Wizard/Witch Doctor) doing Inferno?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72705/what-stats-are-best-for-casters-wizard-witch-doctor-doing-inferno)

I am curious what stats are more viable now after patch 1.0.3 (should I buy items with crit or still attack speed?). And also how much resists and HP should I have to be OK in Act II?

I have ~470 resists, 24k hp and 21k damage buffed (after patch), but I play with barb with resist buff so I get near 600 resists. Should I buy more items with int/vit and not care a lot about resist all, because I'll get some from int and the barb?

Comment: I think this question should maybe be edited back to reflect that it's asking about changes from the patch. It's not just a Wizard Inferno Stats question (in fact, we have [plenty of those](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiablo-3%5D+wizard+%2Binferno+%2Bstats&submit=search) already).

Comment: Voting to close - the [previous question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72705/what-stats-are-best-for-casters-wizard-witch-doctor-doing-inferno) asking the same thing should just be updated with new answers, if there's anything new to update.  Having a new question after every patch will quickly cause us to have lots of questions that are too localized (in time) as more patches come out.

Comment: Hi Stals, scoping questions to a single minor patch is too ephemeral for the Stack Exchange format: we're not a discussion board in that respect. As BlueRaja mentioned, the canonical question we have on the subject should just be updated with the latest information instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're *consistently* playing with a Barbarian who is buffing your resistances, in addition to being your meat shield, then your gearing strategy should be similar to pre-patch with more focus on damage output (your health and resists are reasonable and more than sufficient to kill up to Azmodan and beyond, depending on your skill level). Your focus on damage output should not totally neglect Increased Attack Speed as it is still a good stat, but it shouldn't focus on it as your primary stat. Remember that the mechanic itself wasn't nerfed, only the value of IAS on items.

Stacking intellect is always good as it has additional effects (gaining more resists). A balanced combination of Critical Hit Chance and Critical Hit Damage % will give you a noticeable increase to DPS as well. The largest single factor in damage output for casters/ranged in general is still the damage range on weapons.

You say that your damage is 21K while *buffed* - are you using both Force Weapon and Familiar, or is this value with just one of them? 21K damage after being buffed by either of these abilities is low - aim for at least 25K+ *unbuffed* to have an easier time of killing enemies.

Comment: 21k with Force Weapon. Thx for the answer.

Comment: 21k while playing with a friend is probably sufficient for most of Act 2 now that the changes have gone through in patch 1.0.3; if you are not having trouble killing enemies then don't worry too much about it until you get to a point that you are.

Comment: If a Monk with 12K DPS can make it, 21K is easily enough.

Comment: Monk has defensive abilities, for every bit more survivability a melee class has, a ranged class needs more DPS or far more survivability, baring in mind that Monks have a 30% damage reduction on top of your statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I feel that in tight situations such as arcane bosses that toss you, the difference between having 30k hp and 5k hp are practically negligible. In most situations, simply avoiding projectiles/enemies is usually enough to keep you from taking any damage.

Keeping this in mind, my build is 45k damage pre-Force Weapon buff - I instead opt for force shield which reduces incoming attacks to 35% of your health - there is no difference between tanking a 7000dmg attack with 21k hp and tanking it with force shield.

Of course, this build works well for me but certainly won't work well for everyone - in pubs, I tend to die a lot, but with my monk friend who can pull all the enemies to him for me to comet, the build really shines.