# How should I improve my Demonhunter after the patch 1.0.3?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I play a Demonhunter in Diablo 3 and I am stuck.

Nothing has changed in the difficulty regarding the Demonhunter. I can survive 1 hit from "normal" monsters but Elites and Bosses usually still kill me with one hit.

The problem is that I am not allowed to die that often. Dying about 5-6 times costs 19k and each "run" brings me about 50k. So if I have a good run I can make about 20-30k. But if there are some nasty Elites even 10k is good.

I dropped from feeling comfortable in Act II to feeling comfortable in Act I.

This is ridiculous. I actually do not improve. I play and play and my items stay the same, even my money does not increase.

I tried different alternatives like making my char more tanky or dealing more basic damage instead of relying on criticals, but then I cannot kill the Elites as they still deal huge damage and I do not want to kite them like 10 minutes.

I think Diablo is not a MMORPG and I do not want to grind and hope for some really lucky item drop. I mean I get about 10 rares per hour and usually these are really crappy.

So how can I improve my Demonhunter? What should I actually do like what quests etc.? I want to see some real progress. Otherwise this game is not for me anymore.

Comment: Have you thought about 'Ignores Durability Loss' if repair costs are a major concern?

Comment: Voting to close for the same reason as [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74066/what-stats-should-a-wizard-invest-in-inferno#comment102825_74066)

Comment: @ayckoster What is your DPS, armour, life, resists, etc? What do you use as a build, what passives, what attacks, are you stacking any particular stat like Life on Hit or Critical Damage? What weapon are you using? Lots of questions before a reliable answer can be given to you.

Comment: Inferno is supposed to be the difficult level which is a challenge. And which remains a challenge for a long period of time. If you are expecting to be able to power through inferno after a mere 30 hours of farming for gear in act 1, then you simply have the wrong expectations.

Comment: In the chat someone suggested to improve my health from about 16k to 25-30k. That solved my problem, as I do not need to use SS on every monster and thus I have enough discipline when it counts.

Comment: @ayckoster also apply liberal use of caltrops.  I use the immobilize one and it will often keep me safe for a very short time when monsters get too close.  It helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting one-shot in ActII after 1.03, you're almost certainly undergeared. Also, Diablo may not be an MMORPG, but it *is* about grinding for gear. That's the bad news.

The good news is that the new drop mechanics mean that with 5 stacks of NV, elite packs are guaranteed to drop a rare. With 150% MF, I regularly see 2 or 3 rares per pack. On top of that, Blizzard has increased the odds of seeing level 61 (17%), 62 (8%) and even 63 items (2%) in ActI.

As for the money, I tend to just grind the Battlefields on ActIII/Hell with a GF set. This nets me about 300k per hour very safely. I've also had to unlearn a few things that cheap repair costs have let me get away with up to now. Spam potions, and always be ready to run away :)

Comment: I never thought of grinding Act III / IV hell.